# Import csv in prestashop from an external URL

Tags: import, prestashop

I'm wondering if is possible somehow to import products from a csv which is allocated in an url instead of from a file.

I need this this because the online shop I'm creating has a product list which is dependant from my main suplier and he has allocated his products in an csv URL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible! I have made lot of import/feed scripts using CSV files. Its like XML. Take content, read it and add/update.